# JavaFX WebView won't load localhost website

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to load a localhost website in a JavaFX WebView, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm creating the HttpServer in the application before loading the webpage, but it only shows a blank screen. Navigating to http://localhost:8080/index.html in Google Chrome works so I'm guessing it must be a problem with the WebView trying to load it. Loading other, non localhost pages does work but I cannot figure out why the localhost pages are having problems.

The code below starts by creating the HttpServer with local html files, and then goes on to create the JavaFX stage and load the localhost site into a WebView, only to show a blank page.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    static String path = "";
    static HashMap<String, String> pages = new HashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        createPage(server, "/index.html", "index.html");
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();

        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            WebView webview = new WebView();
            webview.getEngine().load(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html"
            );
            webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

            stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
            stage.show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            try {
                String response = readFile(pages.get(t.getHttpContext().getPath()), Charset.defaultCharset());
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
                OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
                os.write(response.getBytes());
                os.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static void createPage(HttpServer server, String context, String path){
        pages.put(context, path);
        server.createContext(context, new MyHandler());
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

}
```

Any help in trying to solve this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can it load other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length()); to t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0); seemed to fix the problem for me.